# ElasticSearch using incorrect JVM

Tags: java, elasticsearch, path, jvm, java-6

I'm using ElasticSearch v.1.0.1. I start and stop elasticsearch using the init.d script

`$ sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start/stop`

my JAVA_HOME shows the correct JVM:

`$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0`

Also, my Java version seems completely fine

`$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)`

But when I start my elasticsearch instance, and check the status of my node using

`curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_nodes?jvm=true&pretty=true"`

I get the output:

`{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "nodes" : {
    .
    .
    .
    .
      "jvm" : {
        "pid" : 24498,
        "version" : "1.6.0_32",
        "vm_name" : "OpenJDK Client VM",
        "vm_version" : "23.25-b01",
        "vm_vendor" : "Sun Microsystems Inc.",
        "start_time" : 1425803965875,
        "mem" : {
     .
     .
     .
     .
     },
      "plugins" : [ ]
    }
  }
}`

which is implying that I'm using JVM 1.6 for running elasticsearch.

How can I ensure that elasticsearch runs using the JVM 1.7 that is set in JAVA_HOME?

Thanks

Comment: Init scripts does not know about your personal variables. You need to look at the script more closely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a unix user but I'll try to help.

This happened to me under Windows with Elastic 1.4.0, after I had to get rid of Java and reinstall it completely.

I had to reinstall the Elastic service using service.bat in the /bin folder.

```
...\elasticsearch-1.4.0\bin> .\service.bat install
Installing service      :  "elasticsearch-service-x64"
Using JAVA_HOME (64-bit):  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65"
The service 'elasticsearch-service-x64' has been installed.
```

From the console output it seems that the JAVA_HOME is figured out only once, when the "install" command is run. If you were to change the JAVA_HOME variable Elastic will ignore it.

I'm not sure for Linux but I guess you'll have to run something like

```
<elastic-deamon> stop
<elastic-deamon> remove
<elastic-deamon> install
<elastic-deamon> start
```

Whatever  might be for you.
 remove is only removing the deamon and shouldn't affect your data. But I advise to do a backup first...

Editing /bin/ElasticSearch or /bin/service.bat as pointed in https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10611 didn't give any result.

Hope it helped...